# How to get rid of the browser's native TEXTAREA highlighting?

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, border

How can I control the browser's native textarea highlighting? Twitter's status textarea is a good example for that. They fade in a lighter border. Can it be removed completely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `outline` property to control the highlighting:

```
textarea {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Remember however that a `:focus` style is useful for accessibility reasons, so you'd probably want to highlight focused fields in some manner, such as with a light background:

```
textarea:focus { 
   background-color: #FFEFC6;
}
```